# Is there an element on the page through the IF statement. Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

Good day.

Faced a problem on the Selenium IDE Version 3.17.0.
There is a button on the page, if it is present, then click on it, if not, then click on another button.
Tell me, please, how can this be implemented through the IF operator in the Selenium IDE?

P.S.

Tried through `$ {! StatusOK}` - this does not work.

Also tried such a scheme, but also does not work, since I don’t understand what to pass to the "element":

```
if | element.IsVisible() |

click | linkText="text" | 

else 

click | css=%path_css_locator%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do stuff to the element before you find it.  You have to wait for timeout when trrying to find the element, and catch the exception.

Comment: Please tell me how to find this element through the command "execute script"?

Comment: The problem is that if you look for the element through the "assert element present" command, then in case of an error the test will end. And how to combine it with "try / catch", I do not understand.

Comment: The “find element” command will not work, because if there is no element on the page, the program code ends. I need to handle the search condition for an element on a page through the execute script command. I do like this: 

`execute script | try{var a = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-lg btn-active")[0]; return a;} catch(Notfound) {} | a` 

But it gives an error 

`executeScript on try{var a = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-lg btn-active")[0]; return a;} catch(Notfound) {} with value a Failed:
e.match is not a function`

Comment: I'm also trying to take an element by `execute script | try{var a = document.querySelectorAll("div.confirmation-popup__btn:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)")[0]; return a;} catch(Notfound) {}`. But it gives an error  `Failed: e.match is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Did the task. It was necessary to write like this:

`execute script | try{document.querySelector("div.confirmation-popup__btn:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)").click();} catch(Notfound) {document.querySelector(".js-address-modal-open > span").click();}`

Here we click on the element. If this does not happen, then click on another element.